# What IP does my web server connect to after I set up replica set in Mongo?

Tags: unix, database, replication, mongodb

1. Install Mongo on A.  Start the server: $ mongod --rest --replSet myset
2. rs.initiate() on A.
3. Install Mongo on B. Start the server: $ mongod --rest --replSet myset
4. Connect to A and add B to the set: rs.add("B");
5. Set up C as the Arbiter: $ mongod --rest --replSet myset --oplogSize
6. Connect to A and add C as an arbiter:  rs.add( { host:”C”, arbiterOnly:true }

Alright, my question is:

**What Mongo server does my web server connect to? Before replica set, it's very simple. I just give it a host, user, pass, and the web server connects perfectly.  But with all of this set up, how does the web server know whether to point to A, or to B, or to C?**

I'm guessing that the web server should always point to C, and it will handle everything magically?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.construct.php will help you even if you are not using PHP. You can connect to any server in the RS, the rest is the driver's role (and every driver does it). Specifying several to connect to makes it possible for the driver to connect to the RS should one server fail.

Comment: I'm using mongoosejs.com.  It doens't seem like this does it.